# Admob test ad display but after creating sign apk and publish on playstore real ad not display

Tags: android

Admob test ad display but after creating sign apk and publish on playstore real ad not display. I publish app before two days but till not read ad display.

Comment: Make sure you didn't use the Test AdUnit Ids.

Comment: I confirm it's not test adunit id

Comment: Also check if you have used the correct **APP_ID** or added your current device as a Test Device on the dashboard, If so then use a different device & install the app.